# How to migrate Postgres SQL from one region to another region in Google cloud platform

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

In my gcp project App engine located in Central US and my Postgres Sql located in East US region.

Any one suggest best way to resolve the connection and latency issue for the above problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? In the title you ask how to "migrate from one region to anothe", but in the description you ask about latency. So what is your question then?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide more info on what you are trying to achieve, efforts you made...

Comment: Can you clarify what is the exact question you'd like to address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand there is high latency between your app engine and PostgreSql instance. You can avoid high latency if you enable Geo-replication for your instances.
You can also migrate your instances closer to each other but overall latency across the world would increase significantly.
So my suggestion would be to go for geo-replication.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps to migrate the GCP SQL instance from one region to other region:

1. Create read-replica of the SQL instance into the desired region
2. Promote the read-replica to primary instance

This way we can move the SQL instance hassle free on GCP SQL from one region to other region